# How to serialize a pypbc.element type data? (pypbc)

Tags: python, serialization, cryptography

I am currently working on a project related to data integrity auditing, which uses the `pypbc` library. I need to send `pypbc.element` type data from one host to another, but I don't know how to convert it to bytes type.

```
python 3.7.5
pbc 0.5.14
pypbc 0.2
```

[image]

I've tried using some third-party libraries, but none of them support the `pypbc.element` type. I also tried using the element_to_bytes function from the PBC library in C, but that didn't work either. I've also checked the element class, but I didn't find a function or method that can do this.
So what can I do?